# Attribute class not allowed on element span at this point

Tags: html, html5

Валидатор выдаёт ошибку

```
Attribute class not allowed on element span at this point.
```

В спецификации для span указано:

```
Content attributes: Global attributes
```

Class относится к global attributes.

Вот код:

```
<section class='video-box'> 
              <div class="shape">Яндекс.Авто за минуту</div>
              <span class="play-btn"></span>
              <img src="pictures/Video_snapshot.png" alt=""></section>
            <h1 class="font-47">Простой способ выбрать автомобиль</h1>
            <section class="promo-grid__row">
                <img class="icon col-1" src="pictures/383.png " alt='' >
                <h5 class='promo-grid__header col-1'>Каталог</h5>
                <span сlass='promo-grid__decsr col-1'>Самый большой каталог с описанием автомобилей от современных — до 20 лет назад</span>
                <img class="icon col-2" src="pictures/529.png  " alt=''>
                <h5 class='promo-grid__header col-2'>Поиск</h5>
                <span сlass='promo-grid__decsr col-2'>Возможность искать по большему числу параметров, чем где бы то ни было</span>
                <img class="icon col-3" src="pictures/348.png" alt="">
                <h5 class='promo-grid__header col-3'>Выборки автомобилей</h5>
                <span сlass='promo-grid__decsr col-3'>Выборки автомобилей в зависимости от ваших потребностей: «семейный», «для города», «для путешествий»</span>
                <img class="icon col-4" src="pictures/269.png" alt="">
                <h5 class='promo-grid__header col-4'>Простой язык</h5>
                <span сlass='promo-grid__decsr col-4'>Возможность описания характеристик простым языком, понятным неискушенному пользователю</span>
            </section>
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<span сlass='promo-grid__decsr ...
```

Здесь символ "с" в "сlass" - из кириллицы. Поменяйте на латинское "c" - как в остальных элементах.